# Python 2 different datatype comparison

Tags: python

Can someone tell how Python 2 compares different data types. For instance -

```
a = [1,2]
b = {1,2}
c = (1,2)

a>b
#False
a>c
#False
c>b
#True
```

What is the basis of this comparison?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Comment: They are compared by the names of their types, so `list < set < tuple`.

Comment: Full list of Python 2 rules implemented in Python 3: [How can I get 2.x-like sorting behaviour in Python 3.x?](//stackoverflow.com/q/26575183)

Comment: `b = {1,2}` only works in Python 3. But python 3 doesn't not allow this type of comparison: `TypeError: unorderable types: list() < tuple()`

Comment: Thank you Kendas! I don't how I missed the documentation.

Comment: @ChrisLam: The `{.., ..., ...}` set literal syntax works in Python 2.7 too.